# Inserting MySQL data as an image path

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to do simple code like this everything works fine:

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

if($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table")) {
    if($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        echo $row->imgName, ' ',$row->divId, '<br>';
    }
} 
?>
```

But inserting an image is not working for some reason:

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

if($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table")) {
    if($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        echo "<img src='img/".$row['imgName']."' />";
    }
} 
?>
```

Can you help me out, please!

Comment: try this: echo "<img src='~/img/".$row['imgName']."' />"

Comment: If you do fetch_object, you have to use object->syntax. If you do fetch_assoc, you have to use array['syntax'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$row['imgName']` to `$row->imgName`

Comment: how about insert image inside div it seems like this code doesn't work: echo '<div id="one"><img src="img/'.$row->imgName.'" alt="'.htmlspecialchars($row->imgId).'" /></div>';